# Specific Question about the Exponential Distribution

Tags: probability

I think the best way to ask this question is to make up a scenario.

> While Jeremy is sitting in a park he notices bees land on a particular type of flower according to a Poisson process with a rate of $0.4$. As time passes Jeremy nods off. $20$ minutes later Jeremy 'comes to',  and notices a flower with a bee on it. What is the probability that the bee landed on the flower between $t = 18$ and $t = 20$?

Take the point where Jeremy falls asleep to be $t = 0$.

We have $T\sim \text{Exp}(0.4)$ where $T$ is the event that a bee lands on a flower in time $t$. We also have $B(t) \sim \text{Pois}(0.4)$ where $B(t)$ is the number of bees to pollinate a flower in time $t$?

Since we know that a bee has landed on the flower, do we have to consider a conditional probability? i.e. $Pr( [18 < T < 20]| B(20) = 1)$ or does it suffice to just consider  $Pr(18 < T < 20)$?

---

EDIT:

Consider,

$Pr(B(18) = 0 | B(20) = 1) = \dfrac{Pr(B(2) = 1 )Pr( B(18) = 0)}{Pr(B(20) = 1)}$

Comment: I think it is 1 - P(takes > 2 minutes to pollinate) = 1 - $e^{-0.8}$ I don't understand the relevance of 18 and 20 in your answer - is there more to the question?  (other parts of it?)

Comment: I've updated my question to hopefully make it clearer!

Comment: I think 18-20 minutes don't really matter - it could just as well be 118-120 minutes - the bee is there, and the flower is not pollinated - what is the probability that it has been there less than 2 minutes, given that zero pollinations have occurred?  I'm assuming it's pollination of the flower that is the poisson process, not arrival at the flower- which seems to be the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to consider the conditional probability. To see this, think about the alternative question "what is the probability that the bee was already there at time $18$?"

If $P(18<T<20)$ was the right answer to the original question, presumably the answer to this new question would be $P(T\leq 18)$. Also, we should have the two answers summing to $1$, since one of them must have happened. But $P(18<T<20)+P(T\leq 18)=P(T<20)\neq 1$.

Given that a bee has arrived, for that bee the time of arrival isn't an exponential distribution any more, because it must be between $0$ and $20$. Also, you know that no other bees have arrived in between. So the right probability is $P(B_{18}=0\mid B_{20}=1)$, where $B_t$ is the number of bees arrived by time $t$.

This is $\frac{P(B_{18}=0,B_{20}=1)}{P(B_{20}=1)}$. We can write $B_{20}=B_{18}+X$, where $X\sim\text{Poi}(2\lambda)$ and $B_{18}\sim\text{Poi}(18\lambda)$ are independent; then $B_{20}=1$ and $B_{18}=0$ iff $B_{18}=0$ and $X=1$.

So we have $P(B_{18}=0,B_{20}=1)=P(B_{18}=0,X=1)=e^{-18\lambda}\cdot 2\lambda e^{-2\lambda}$, and $P(B_{20}=1)=20\lambda e^{-20\lambda}$, so the conditional probability is $\frac{2}{20}$ (the $\lambda$'s cancel).

Comment: How would I compute $P(18<T<20\mid T<20)$? $\frac{P([18<T<20 ]\cap [T<20])}{Pr(T < 20)}$

Comment: do we have any information about the distribution of arrival times?  The question only seem to refer to pollination - i'm assuming that the pollination of a flower with a bee on it is the poisson event.  When a bee is on a flower, it is pollinating wilth lambda = 0.4  - what you seem to know is that the bee has created zero pollinations, what proportion of zero pollinators, would not have passed the two minute mark?

Comment: sorry, my initial answer was wrong as I forgot that you are also conditioning on it being the only bee that arrived. Have updated to give correct details.

Comment: Would you say that my edit is analogous to your answer? I've used the property of independence and the fact that Poisson processes model events occurring at random in time to 'divide' the probability into two intervals, namely $B(2)$ and $B(18)$.

Comment: Yes, Poisson processes model arrivals at a uniform rate, so once you know how many arrivals there are, the time of each arrival is uniformly distributed.